# Non-wrapping CSS Flex with fixed widths

Tags: css, flexbox, carousel

I'm building a Carousel-type component, but am having some difficulty getting it to work *just right*.

My basic approach is a div (wrapper) with lots of other divs (items) in it. I want to display 4 items on the carousel at any one time. The items have various content heights, but the heights of the items should be equal (to the largest required).

I can't work out the CSS combination I need to get this to work correctly.

With [this setup](https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/fykqqrmv/4/) (HTML + CSS at bottom of post), the `width: 25%;` on each `item-container` is ignored.

If I add a fixed with to `.item`, then the 25% kicks in, but the item width is unknown -- it depends on the browsers size. Setting it to 1000px means you lose content from the item. Setting it to ~210px works, but when you start shrinking your browser, you lose content. On a large browser, you have excessive spacing.

Curiously, if I add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the CSS, then the 25% width is applied correctly -- but I can't do that, because then it's not a carousel! [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/fykqqrmv/6/)

**The scenario is simple:
An unknown amount of items in a div with `overflow: auto`, which are equal heights should be displayed, with 4 of the children divs on the screen at any one time.**

My HTML is structured as follows:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #1 with some quite long text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #2.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #3.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item-container {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  width: 25%;
}
```

*Note, this is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). On my real component, I have buttons for scrolling left and right, the content is significantly more complex and stuff like that.*

Comment: @Pete Yes, I use JS to handle the scroll buttons -- the carousel works on non-JS browsers too though, by linking to the current page and adding an index to the querystring -- and that's analysed server-side and chops and changes the content as needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add `flex: 0 0 auto` to `.item-container` elements.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item-container {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #1 with some quite long text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #2.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #3.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #4.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #5.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #6.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <p>
          Carousel Item #7.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've battled with this for hours, thank you. The specific property I was missing is `flex-shrink: 0`. The others (`flex-basis: auto; flex-grow: 0;`) are default values.